# Python to extract parts of data from a file

Tags: python

I have data that looks like this

```
{sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf}{sdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdf}{dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf}{dfsdfsdfsfsdfsd}
```

I want a peace of code that can turn it into this

```
{sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf}
{sdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdf}
{dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf}
{dfsdfsdfsfsdfsd}
```

any help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you mean how to print a new line? If so, that's "\n"

Comment: yes i want it to turn them into lines but i keep getting errors

Comment: but only the ones in between brackets is what gets its separate line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on `}` and add it back to each split line slicing off the last `}` or use `re.findall` to match curly braces with anything in between:

```
lines = """{sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf}{sdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdf}{dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf}{dfsdfsdfsfsdfsd}"""

print("\n".join([line+"}" for line in lines.split("}")][:-1]))

{sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf}
{sdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdf}
{dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf}
{dfsdfsdfsfsdfsd}

import  re

print("\n".join(re.findall("(\{.*?\})",lines)))

{sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf}
{sdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdf}
{dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf}
{dfsdfsdfsfsdfsd}
```

From a file:

```
    with open("foo.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
             print("\n".join(re.findall("(\{.*?\})",line)))
```

Comment: my data is in a text file

Comment: You should read a tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/working-with-data.html#working-with-files

Comment: NameError: name 'lines' is not defined

Comment: @HellosAddme, a typo, can you see what the problem was?

Comment: yes, the traceback always gives you a good clue. You're welcome.

Comment: one more thing,how do i make it output to another file